# LinkButton OnCommand not called in User Control

Tags: asp.net

In my usercontrol, I have a repeater that contains some data from the DB.  Here's the Item Template

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td class="tblCell">
                    <a href="Document.aspx?docId=<%# Eval("DOCID") %>" target="_blank">
                        <%# Eval("FILENAME") %></a>
                </td>
                <td class="tblCell">
                <asp:Label ID="_empty" runat="server" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="_lnkDelete" runat="server" OnCommand="LinkDelete_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DOCID") %>' Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Delete this Document?')" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

The Repeater shows a list of files, and each filename has it's own delete button.  The delete button however, doesn't call the OnCommand event when clicked.  It just posts back.

```
protected void LinkDelete_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    MyObject _myObj = new MyObject(Convert.ToInt64(e.CommandArgument));
    _myObj.Deleted = "Y";
    _myObj.Update();
    DeleteFile(_myObj.Filename);
    GetFileInfo();
}
```

Is there some problem with using a LinkButton in this way within a user control?  If so, is there some workaround?  Or is the problem obvious, and I'm just not seeing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You have forgotten to define the [CommandName](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandname.aspx&rct=j&q=linkbutton%20commandname&ei=es3ZTNCHE4efOq2SscAJ&usg=AFQjCNEYm2hRhGrycyXUKRBscDks2VtTfg&sig2=mEaOVExB7gxezXgmkC09GA&cad=rja). In your situation `delete` would be appropriate.</strike>

**EDIT**: You should catch it in the Repeater's [OnItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx).

Comment: That didn't change anything.  When debugging, it's not even hitting the break point at LinkDelete_Click.  Thanks

Comment: Hmm, sorry, my fault. Tested without repeater. Look at my update.

Comment: I'm sure that would work too, but I finally found the problem... for some reason I had "EnableViewState = "False" on the repeater (which I unfortunately didn't post).  Thanks for the help though!